# Issue posting variable with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, arrays, variables, sdk, nsstring

I am encountering an issue while posting a variable with Xcode:

While running this code the app crashes while posting the variable to a webservice:

```
NSArray *array = [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
NSString *time = [array objectAtIndex:1];
UTCorLocal = time;
NSLog(@"%@", UTCorLocal);
```

UTCorLocal variable is declared earlier in the code. The NSLog outputs the correct string, but when I try to use it further along in the code it crashes.

When I give the variable a static value like this:

```
UTCorLocal = @"UTC";
```

It all runs like it should do!

Could anybody please help, it's driving me crazy!

Thanks a lot,

Ron

Comment: The error message of your app crash would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: That's the strange thing. It doesn't give an error message. It just exits and that's the end of it!

Comment: Okay, this is what it outputs as error: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. That's all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably released somewhere along the way, I would guess, without knowing the rest of your code. Try copying or retaining 'time' and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what do you exactly mean by copying or retaining the variable? Do you mean I should alloc it or is there another way? Thanks!

Comment: It was a releasing problem I think. I changed the code to: UTCorLocal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",time]; And now everything works fine!